# Connections with the Excel and Access Database are preventing me from getting exclusive database

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an access database that users are connecting to with excel files.  I have way of managing people who are logged on using Access.  However,  I do not have a way to manage people who are connected to the database using excel.  It is my front in so I am not worried about the Data I just want to be able to edit forms and add features.

Comment: Simply split your architecture into multiple FrontEnds and one BackEnd. Have Excel users (Excel being a special FrontEnd) connect directly to the BackEnd mdb/accdb file of data tables and maintain a separate Access FrontEnd for your UI application. Recall this split system is like all software and web apps where there can be many clients connecting to a single data source.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting your database will help...https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Split-an-Access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc

But you can also look into making the FE you release to users as an mde or accde file.  These will compile your VBA code and not allow users to enter design mode to change anything so these files are slightly smaller and more secure.

Then you can make changes to the regular FE mdb or accdb files that you have, test those changes and then when you are ready to release a new version, publish them as mde or accde files and copy it over the old version (or make back ups first, and then replace).

Comment: I have seen this before but is it possible for users to make changes to tables when doing this.

Comment: If you mean the table setup...column names, data types...that sort of thing.  No...they would have no design view abilities at all.  The tables would be in the Back End, and they don't access that file directly.

Comment: Did you have any more questions regarding split databases?